# System unable to boot Windows and any booting device

Tags: windows, boot, desktop-computer

My System Fujitsu Siemens Scaleo P cannot boot windows and doesn't proceed after display of Fujitsu Siemens Logo (Where it says Press F2 to Enter Setup).

The System has USB only port for Keyboard and Mouse but Keyboard isn't detected (No power on Keyboard LEDs). 
Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried another keyboard? Another USB port? Maybe the system is waiting for the keyboard. Without the keyboard there is not much you can do. You can reset the CMOS from the jumper located on the motherboard or removing battery and power from your PC for 10 20 minutes. Have you tried anyway to press f2 to see if it get you into the Bios Setup?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I would run a memory tester

http://www.memtest.org/

Download the prebuilt ISO, burn it to CD as an Image (not data), boot from that CD and run the memory test for a couple of hours or overnight to stress test the memory.